# Fetch multiple resultset from SQL Server in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the code
    $exec = "EXEC RPT_TEST_2resultSet";
    $resultSet = \DB::select($exec);

SP is returning 3 result sets. But in php it prints first set of result set only. How to fetch the other 2 set of result sets? Tried the solution suggested by others. Was getting some other errors.

Comment: Tried already, its giving some other error   SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The given attribute is only supported on the PDOStatement object.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, this isnt even a duplicate if u didnt read the SQLSERVER instead of MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

Make a foreach

check example:

```
foreach ($resultSet as $result) {
   echo $result['someDataFromResult'];
}
```

This will repeat for the amount of data is in the $resultSet array

Answer (score 0):

Found the simple solution for this problem.

```
$pdo = \DB::connection()->getPdo();
$sql = 'EXEC Test_SP_MultiResultSet';
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
do {
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM); // Keys will be start from zero , one, two
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Column names will be assigned for each value

   if ($rows) {
    $sheetData[] = $rows;
   }
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

[Source Link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSNY3_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0023501.html)